# SolidWorks VBA Macro : Select all holes

Tags: solidworks

is there a methode for automatically select all holes in a drawing view?

something like:

```
status = swModelDocExt.SelectByID2("Drawingview1", "VERTEX", 8.76609155372049E-02, 0.255953076919585, -499.97349537912, False, 0, Nothing, 0)
```

but for every hole